# Send Thousands of Post Data to Page using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

```
import urllib,urllib2

for x in range(0, 10000):
    url = '127.0.0.1/post.php'
    parameters = {'id' : '5'}
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)    # Use urllib to encode the parameters
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)    # This request is sent in HTTP POST
    page = response.read(1)
    print x
```

I have this basic script in a loop. But is it possible to send thousands of post data to the page very fast ?

I am new to this. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying a DDoS attack? ;-)

Comment: no. Just starting out with scraping and load testing. so.

Comment: I have performed some load testing earlier, it is possible using your code as well but then the requests will be sent in after the other and not in one shot. Adding code snippet and output for your refernce

Comment: You could use multiple threads.

Comment: as I am completely new to this. Can you share some of your ideas ? or codes.

Comment: oh cmon ? No answers ?????

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.2.1/'
count = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    if source_code.status_code == 200:
        count +=1
    print(count)
```

Output: C:\Python34\python.exe "E:/python study/Multiple request.py"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

If you want it perform load testing then probably go for JMeter, i have used it in the past it is simple to use.

Comment: I am looking for something which will enable me to perform post request on a page on a scale of hundreds or thousands ? Do you have a advise for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to try to re-invent the wheel and look for a load testing tool which could do that for you. For instance [Locust](http://locust.io/) and [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) testing framework are Python-based.

Other free and open source load testing tools are:

- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide which contains sample tests, load reports and features comparison matrix, hopefully you'll find a right option.